# Javascript write a for loop for elements inside of a function

Tags: javascript

```
editArticleService.show(item.facility, item.administrator, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q18, q19, q20, q21, q22, q23, q24, q25, q26, q27, q28, q29, q30, q31, q32, q33, q34, q35, q36, q37, q38, q39, q40, q41, q42, q43, q44, q45, q46, q47, q48, q49, q50, q51, q52, q53, q54, q55, q56) {
```

I have the above statement in my code, as you can see it's unnecessarily long - something which we would classically say write a loop for... The issue is I don't normally code in javascript so I am not familiar how to correctly do this. So then I would say something like this:

```
    var step;
    var qvalues = 'item.q0';
    for (step = 1; step < 57; step++) {
        qvalues += ',item.q'+step;
    }

  editArticleService.show(item.facility, item.administrator, qvalues).then(function(result) {
```

Below is the complete code for context:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('firebase-starter-admin.articles')
    .controller('ArticlesController', ArticlesController);

  ArticlesController.$inject = ['articlesService', '$ionicListDelegate', 'editArticleService', '$state'];

  /* @ngInject */
  function ArticlesController(articlesService, $ionicListDelegate, editArticleService, $state) {
    var vm = angular.extend(this, {
      items: [],
      addItem: addItem,
      deleteItem: deleteItem,
      updateItem: updateItem,
      openDetails: openDetails
    });

    (function activate() {
      selectAll();
    })();

    // ********************************************************************

    function openDetails(item) {
      $state.go('app.article', {
        id: item.$id
      });
    }

    function deleteItem(item) {
      articlesService.deleteItem(item);
    }

    function updateItem(item) {
      $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();

            var step;
            var qvalues = 'item.q0';
            for (step = 1; step < 57; step++) {
                qvalues += ',item.q'+step;
            }

      editArticleService.show(item.facility, item.administrator, qvalues).then(function(result) {

        if (result.canceled) {
          return;
        }

        articlesService.saveItem(item.$id, {
          facility: result.facility,
          administrator: result.administrator,

          q1: result.q1,
          q2: result.q2,
          q3: result.q3,
          q4: result.q4,
          q5: result.q5,
          q6: result.q6,
          q7: result.q7,
          q8: result.q8,
          q9: result.q9,
          q10: result.q10,
          q11: result.q11,
          q12: result.q12,
          q13: result.q13,
          q14: result.q14,
          q15: result.q15,
          q16: result.q16,
          q17: result.q17,
          q18: result.q18,
          q19: result.q19,
          q20: result.q20,
          q21: result.q21,
          q22: result.q22,
          q23: result.q23,
          q24: result.q24,
          q25: result.q25,
          q26: result.q26,
          q27: result.q27,
          q28: result.q28,
          q29: result.q29,
          q30: result.q30,
          q31: result.q31,
          q32: result.q32,
          q33: result.q33,
          q34: result.q34,
          q35: result.q35,
          q36: result.q36,
          q37: result.q37,
          q38: result.q38,
          q39: result.q39,
          q40: result.q40,
          q41: result.q41,
          q42: result.q42,
          q43: result.q43,
          q44: result.q44,
          q45: result.q45,
          q46: result.q46,
          q47: result.q47,
          q48: result.q48,
          q49: result.q49,
          q50: result.q50,
          q51: result.q51,
          q52: result.q52,
          q53: result.q53,
          q54: result.q54,
          q55: result.q55,
          q56: result.q56
        });
      });
    }

    function selectAll() {
      vm.items = articlesService.selectAll();
    }

    function addItem() {
      editArticleService.show().then(function(result) {
        if (result.canceled) {
          return;
        }

        // pre-initialize the answers
        vm.data = {
          q1: '1'
        };

        var item = {
          facility: result.facility,
          administrator: result.administrator,

          q1: result.q1,
          q2: result.q2,
          q3: result.q3,
          q4: result.q4,
          q5: result.q5,
          q6: result.q6,
          q7: result.q7,
          q8: result.q8,
          q9: result.q9,
          q10: result.q10,
          q11: result.q11,
          q12: result.q12,
          q13: result.q13,
          q14: result.q14,
          q15: result.q15,
          q16: result.q16,
          q17: result.q17,
          q18: result.q18,
          q19: result.q19,
          q20: result.q20,
          q21: result.q21,
          q22: result.q22,
          q23: result.q23,
          q24: result.q24,
          q25: result.q25,
          q26: result.q26,
          q27: result.q27,
          q28: result.q28,
          q29: result.q29,
          q30: result.q30,
          q31: result.q31,
          q32: result.q32,
          q33: result.q33,
          q34: result.q34,
          q35: result.q35,
          q36: result.q36,
          q37: result.q37,
          q38: result.q38,
          q39: result.q39,
          q40: result.q40,
          q41: result.q41,
          q42: result.q42,
          q43: result.q43,
          q44: result.q44,
          q45: result.q45,
          q46: result.q46,
          q47: result.q47,
          q48: result.q48,
          q49: result.q49,
          q50: result.q50,
          q51: result.q51,
          q52: result.q52,
          q53: result.q53,
          q54: result.q54,
          q55: result.q55,
          q56: result.q56
        };

        articlesService.insert(item);
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

Thought this be better for CR than SO since the code works, its just I don't know how to write loops properly in this context.

Comment: Please **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: You should use arrays and `push` method or hashtables (objects). This is covered in basic JS tutorials.

Comment: Have any of the answers provided a solution? If so, would you like to mark one of them as the accepted answer, to remove your question from the unanswered list?

Answer (score 2):

```
(function activate() {
  selectAll();
})();
```

I don't see the point in wrapping the call in a function. Just `selectAll()` will do.

---

```
// ********************************************************************
```

I think this is unnecessary. If you want clear separation of code, I usually suggest you write in the following order:

1. Variable declarations
2. Function declarations
3. Operations (assignments, function calls etc.)

The reasoning is that, as far as memory serves, variable declarations and function declarations are "hoisted" (picked up on the first pass on the code). The order above mimics the order the engine sees up the code, thus its easier to visualize what's going on.

---

```
articlesService.saveItem(item.$id, {
  facility: result.facility,
  administrator: result.administrator,
  q1: result.q1,
  ...
  q56: result.q56
});
```

Consider using an array of objects for your `q1` to `q56`. Much cleaner, concise, and you have easy access to array methods.

```
var qData = [
  {name: 'q1', value: result.q56}
  ...
];

articlesService.saveItem(item.$id, {
  facility: result.facility,
  administrator: result.administrator,
  qData: qData
});
```

It also makes sense from an object-oriented point of view. `facility` and `administrator` appear to be properties of one entity. `q*` appears to be its own entity. This appears to be a one-to-many relationship of 2 types of entities.

Answer (score 2):

To build upon Joseph the Dreamer's answer, using an array of Objects here makes a lot of sense. You have access to all the array methods, including specific Object mapping methods, such as `Object.keys(my_object).map(...)`.

Regarding general for-loops in Javascript when iterating through an array, I suggest using the `.map()` approach as I believe the code looks much clearer:

```
var my_array = [...];

my_array.map(function(element){
  //...
});
```